# How to access attempt number from inside Laravel DB Transaction?

Tags: php, laravel

This is a simplified version of what I'm planning to do,

This Transaction is set to retry 5 times for example.

How can I access the attempt number from inside transaction?

```
DB::transaction(function ()
{
    $number = 1;

    if($ATTEMPT_NUMBER > 1){ // <-- How do I know attempt number? (e.g. #2 of 5 attempts)
         $number += $ATTEMPT_NUMBER;
    }

    DB::update("update table set something = {$number}");

    //... other DB stuff here

}, 5); // <-- 5 Attempts
```

I've tried:

```
$counter = 0;
DB::transaction(function () use ($counter)
{
    $number = 1 + $counter++;

    DB::update("update table set something = {$number}");

}, 5);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it would be useful to let us know what you are trying to achieve in case there's a better way to do it:

Broadly speaking if you want to modify a variable that is `use`ed in the scope of a callback you  need to use it by refrence:

```
$counter = 0;
DB::transaction(function () use (&$counter)
{
    $number = 1 + $counter++;
    DB::update("update table set something = {$number}");
}, 5);
```

However keep in mind since this is happening **within** a failing transaction the update will not actially "stick" until the transaction succeeds.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I also tried with reference and it didn't work either, is there no way to access that `$currentAttempt` var in Laravel's transaction? 

What I'm trying to do, is creating a unique number for each user, this cannot be auto-increment, because it starts from middle and randomly increments or decrements and also it is a composite unique key and resets (e.g. it starts with 50, then it is randomly 51 or 49 next time, then 52 or 48). Was trying to increment it in case it keeps failing. In the transaction I am selecting the lowest and highest values, then add (or reduce) 1 and apply.

Comment: As far as I know Laravel doesn't expose that. You can do a manual loop and call `beginTransaction` .... `commit` or `rollback` like the [transaction method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php#L20) actually does internally, though I don't know why the above would not work. There may be other things at play here as well

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do the manual loop then, was too focused on figuring this variable out that I completely forgot it can be done manually :D